# ReactiveCommands - Are the following solutions equivalent?

Tags: .net, architecture, software-design, reactiveui

Solution A)

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CommandDoStuff => this._commandDoStuff;
private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> _commandDoStuff;

this._commandDoStuff = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
{
  //pass in parameters directly, do stuff, handle output maybe with an interaction, return Unit;
  var result = await DoStuff(this.Parameter);
  SharedInteraction.Handle(result);
  return;
});

this._commandDoStuff.Execute().Subscribe();
```

Solution B)

```
public ReactiveCommand<T, T> CommandDoStuff => this._commandDoStuff;
private readonly ReactiveCommand<T, T> _commandDoStuff;

this._commandDoStuff = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async (T) =>
{
  //do stuff, return T
  var result = await DoStuff(T);
  return result;
});

this._commandDoStuff.Execute(T).Subscribe(t =>
{
  //handle output maybe with an interaction
  SharedInteraction.Handle(t);
  return;
});
```

I know these are lame questions, but its an effort to avoid asking opinion-based questions...

Are both solutions "valid"?

Are both solutions equivalent? If not, what is the difference?

Is one solution more performant?

Does one solution surface bugs more often than the other?

Does one solution follow a software engineering paradigm more than the other?

You get what I'm asking! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to avoid an opinion based answer.  I'll do my best to stick to what I believe I know.

`Interactions` are about control flow.  I have some function that is happening in my ViewModel, while my ViewModel has control.  I need input from the user in order to complete this function.  I will surface an `Interaction` to get that information from the user.

So to answer, it depends on where you need the information surfaced.

When you subscribe to the execution of the `ReactiveCommand` you are really subscribing to its execution.  That means the command will execute and then your code in `Subscribe()` will execute.  This adds little value if you are expecting the `Interaction` to surface information the `ReactiveCommand` needs in order to complete.

That said if you are simply alerting the user via an `Interaction` that the command completed, then this might not be a problem.

The performance will be determined by what the operation is.

Did you have a particular paradigm in mind, or just looking for the elusive "Best Practices"?

Generally, Stack Overflow doesn't like these open-ended questions because there is no concrete answer to it.

Comment: Awesome! That's is exactly what I was looking for and seems concrete to me, thank you!

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as the correct answer.